# How Uvicorn workers manages GPU memory?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, gunicorn, worker, uvicorn

I use a GPU with high memory (~50Gb) to deal with heavy ML tasks in Pytorch.

Every task needs between 15Gb and 25Gb, and the GPU can only handle 2 workers.

Sometimes, having 2 workers makes some processes longer, even if there are enough power resources to deal with 2 processes in parallel without slowing down.

If there are 3 workers, there is sometimes a Cuda memory error, probably because of the 25Gb process scenario.

It seems that Uvicorn divides the GPU resources equally, including GPU memory, RAM, and processors (vCPUs), but there is no documentation about this behavior.

In the default setting, does Uvicorn actually divide the GPU resources evenly?

Is it possible to assign different resources to every worker?

According to some sources, Gunicorn seems more appropriate than Unicorn, but there is still little information, and mostly not about GPUs:

https://medium.com/@satendra.pratap/gunicorn-worker-configuration-for-memory-8fad59c0a051

Is there another Python library that manages GPUs better than Uvicorn or Gunicorn?

I am surprised that such a crucial problem has so little information, above all, when there are increasing AI-based services using async Python with Pytorch or TF.

Comment: I don’t think uvicorn or gunicorn care anything about GPU or its memory. They’re there just to process requests. Most requests have nothing to do with GPUs so that functionality is in no way related to their job. They don’t divide CPUs or memory either. If you want to put limits on resources etc then that’s your job to do in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  If vCPUs are busy at 200% when using 2 workers, it means that it naturally increases the resources according to the requests, right? How can I code to limit GPU memory for a function or thread?